# AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'xlabel'

Tags: python, matplotlib

l
have to plot to save after a for loop where l get all the values . Here is my code .
However l get an error at the line: `fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()`:

```
g_i= []
g_train_loss= []
g_valid_loss=[]
g_train_accuracy=[]
g_valid_accuracy=[]
for epoch in range(niter):
        #other computations
        g_i = np.append(g_i, epoch)
        g_train_loss = np.append(g_train_loss, loss_avg.val())
        g_train_accuracy = np.append(g_train_accuracy,accuracy_train)
        g_valid_loss = np.append(g_valid_loss, cost_val)
        g_valid_accuracy = np.append(g_valid_accuracy, accuracy_valid)
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(g_i,g_train_loss,label='train_loss')
ax1.plot(g_i,g_valid_loss,label='valid_loss')
ax1.xlabel("epoch")
ax1.ylabel("loss")
f1=ax1.figure()
f1.savefig('loss.png', bbox_inches='tight')
ax2.plot(g_i,g_train_accuracy,label='train_acc')
ax2.plot(g_i,g_train_accuracy,label='valid_acc')
ax2.xlabel("epoch")
ax2.ylabel("accuracy")
f2=ax2.figure()
f2.savefig('acc.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

l get the following error at

```
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
```

which is :

```
/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py", line 144, in _create_qApp
    raise RuntimeError('Invalid DISPLAY variable')
RuntimeError: Invalid DISPLAY variable
```

Edit1 :
l'm usisng ubuntu 16.04 aws amazon server
l did the following :

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

then l get the following new error : 
    ax1.xlabel("epoch")
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'xlabel'

Comment: That's a system issue, not a code issue.

Comment: You need to tell us what your OS is, how you installed matplotlib, if you have an X server running (assuming you're on a real Ubuntu machine), if you run in a docker environment, and generally read the guidelines on how to ask questions on this site. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry, @BoboDarph, please see my edit. l run it on aws server

Comment: Almost looks like a `sudo` issue.

Comment: Can you try: plt.switch_backend('agg') instead of matplotlib.use('agg'). Sauce: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3466

Comment: @MadPhysicist, sudo error ?

Comment: import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                                                                              plt.switch_backend('agg')          @BoboDarph is this what you mean ?

Comment: Try to read through the whole link I posted, the situation described seems to be very similar to yours. Also note that if no display or virtual display is attached to that machine, your plot will most likely fail with the error you described.

Comment: @BoboDarph, you talk about this error ax1.xlabel("epoch") AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'xlabel' ?

Comment: There are two ways to set the xlabel: `ax.set_xlabel("epoch")`, or `plt.xlabel("epoch")`, but not `ax.xlabel("epoch")`.

Comment: I was talking about your original DISPLAY error.

Comment: @helene. You get a similar message sometimes if you try to run graphical applications as root on the newer X servers.

Comment: @BoboDarph, the original problem l solved it as l did in my edit

Comment: @MadPhysicist, thank you